# Declaratively pass parameters to a feature using activationdependency?

Tags: 2007, feature-activation, feature, feature-stapling

is there a way to declaratively pass parameters to a feature using activationdependency?

I have a feature defined in ONET.XML that i want to move to a feature stapler, but since it has a property defined I want to retain that in the activation dependency. is this possible to do declaratively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean is it possible to have "per activation dependency Feature properties", then unfortunately the answer is no. You can, of course, have declarative properties on the Feature but I guess that's not what you're asking?

Comment: I would like to, declaratively, set properties on features either using FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation or FeatureActivationDependency. If not possible, whats my best alternative?